# Llamar un archivo .php desde un botón sin abrirlo

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Saludos Desarrolladores.

Quisiera mandar a llamar(ejecutar) un archivo .php para que se ejecute lo que tiene dentro, por medio de un botón que estará en otro archivo (paginas que se visualizara).

Este es mi archivo insertarDatos.php que quiero mandar a ejecutar o llamar para que se inserten algunos datos.

```
<?php

require 'dbcon.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM wpam_psmsc_tickets t WHERE t.is_active = 1";

$query_run = mysqli_query($con, $query);

if ($query_run) {
    while ($row = $query_run->fetch_array()) {

        $id = $row['id'];
        $activo = $row['is_active'];
        $cliente = $row['customer'];
        $asunto = $row['subject'];
        $estatus = $row['status'];
        $prioridad = $row['priority'];
        $incidencia = $row['category'];
        $agente = $row['assigned_agent'];
        $fecha_Creacion = $row['date_created'];
        $fecha_Actualizacion = $row['date_updated'];
        $agenteCreado = $row['agent_created'];
        $ip = $row['ip_address'];
        $source = $row['source'];
        $browser = $row['browser'];
        $os = $row['os'];
        $add_recipients = $row['add_recipients'];
        $prev_assignee = $row['prev_assignee'];
        $fecha_Cierre = $row['date_closed'];
        $user_type = $row['user_type'];
        $last_reply_on = $row['last_reply_on'];
        $last_reply_by = $row['last_reply_by'];
        $auth_code = $row['auth_code'];
        $cust_24 = $row['cust_24'];
        $cust_25 = $row['cust_25'];
        $cust_26 = $row['cust_26'];
        $cust_29 = $row['cust_29'];
        $cust_30 = $row['cust_30'];
        $cust_31 = $row['cust_31'];
        $cust_32 = $row['cust_32'];
        $fecha_Atencion = $row['cust_33'];
        $solucion = $row['cust_35'];
?>



    <?php
    }
    ?>


    <?php

}

$query3 = "SELECT * FROM tickets";

$query_run3 = mysqli_query($con, $query3);

if ($query_run3) {
    while ($row = $query_run3->fetch_array()) {

        $ids = $row['id_Tickets'];


    ?>

        <!-- <?php
            }
                ?> -->


    <?php

}


if ($id != $ids || !empty($fecha_Creacion) || !empty($fecha_Cierre) ||  !empty($fecha_Atencion)) {
    $query1 = "INSERT INTO tickets (id_Tickets, is_active, customer, subject, status, priority, category, assigned_agent, date_created, date_updated, agent_created, ip_address, source, browser, os, add_recipients, prev_assignee, date_closed, user_type, last_reply_on, last_reply_by, auth_code, cust_24, cust_25, cust_26, cust_29, cust_30, cust_31, cust_32, cust_33, cust_35 ) SELECT t.id, t.is_active, t.customer, t.subject, t.status, t.priority, t.category, t.assigned_agent, t.date_created, t.date_updated, t.agent_created, t.ip_address, t.source, t.browser, t.os, t.add_recipients, t.prev_assignee, t.date_closed, t.user_type, t.last_reply_on, t.last_reply_by, t.auth_code, t.cust_24, t.cust_25, t.cust_26, t.cust_29, t.cust_30, t.cust_31, t.cust_32, t.cust_33, t.cust_35 FROM wpam_psmsc_tickets t WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tickets WHERE tickets.id_Tickets = t.id)";

    $query_run1 = mysqli_query($con, $query1);

    echo "EXITO, DATOS AGREGADOS A LA TABLA TICKETS";
} else {
    echo "ERROR AL INSERTAR LOS DATOS A LA TABLA TICKETS";
}
```

y quiero ejecutarlo por medio de un botón pero sin que se abra una pagina, ando intentándolo por ajax pero no entiendo bien como realizarlo, no se si me podrían ayudar por favor.

Boton

```
<a class="btn btn-info" title="Ver Registros Incidencias" href="../sistemas/InsertarDatos.php" onclick="actualizarTabla()"></a>
```

Intento de AJAX

```
function actualizarTabla() {
  // AJAX call
  $.ajax({
    url: "../InsertarDatos.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      method: "readCall",
    },
    success: function (response) {
      alert(response);
    },
    error: function (request, error) {
      alert(request);
    },
  });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Al indicar el atributo `href` en el enlace de tu botón, éste abre la dirección que allí hayas indicado (en este caso, la URL que lleva a *InsertarDatos.php*).

Una posibilidad para solucionar esto, es reemplazar el enlace del enlace por una almohadilla (#) y modificar el atributo `onclick` haciéndole pasar el evento al código Javascript. Esto último lo hacemos para, utilizando `eventDefault()`, evitar que al hacer clic en el enlace con almohadilla este haga scroll hacia la parte superior de la pantalla.

De este modo, al hacer clic se ejecuta la función que incluiste en el `onclick` pero no se carga el enlace que hayas definido en el `href`.

**HTML**

```
<a class="btn btn-info" title="Ver Registros Incidencias" href="#" onclick="actualizarTabla(event)"></a>
```

**Javascript**

```
function actualizarTabla(event) {
  // Cancelar el evento
  event.preventDefault();
  // AJAX call
  $.ajax({
    url: "../InsertarDatos.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      method: "readCall",
    },
    success: function (response) {
      alert(response);
    },
    error: function (request, error) {
      alert(request);
    },
  });
}
```